# ¿Cómo hacer para que el From detecte que se ha pulsado un botón del mando de xbox sin usar Threads?

Tags: c#, hilos, controller

Estoy haciendo una aplicacion con Windows Form que se puede controlar con el mando de xbox usando SharpDX por lo que he tenido que crear un Thread para con bucle infinito que tiene esta pinta:

```cs
    private void ControlCapture() 
    {
        while (true)
        {
            control.Update();
            switch (control.Button)
            {
                case GamepadButtonFlags.RightShoulder: app.NextBg(); break;
                case GamepadButtonFlags.LeftShoulder: app.PrevBg(); break;
                default: break;
            }
            Thread.Sleep(10);
        }
    }
```

Básicamente lo que hace es cambiar el ImageBackground del Form principal cargandolas de un archivo con `Image.FronFile("path")`, el fondo también se puede cambiar por las flechitas del teclado. Mi problema es que al hacerlo desde el mando suele saltarme la excepcion `System.InvalidOperationException: 'El objeto ya está en uso.'` sobretodo si los cambio muy rápido.

Se que salta debido a que estoy cambiando el valor de ImageBackground cuando aún esta siendo usado, por ello me gustaría saber si hay alguna forma de implementar la primera función sin usar Threads o si se puede arreglar este problema de concurrencia de alguna forma. El teclado no me da ningún problema sin importar como de rápido los cambie (obviamente tanto el teclado como el mando llaman a la misma función).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Muy buenas Adrián, para evitar este problema siempre puedes utilizar la propiedad `InvokeRequired` del control que intentas actualizar. Te dejo un enlace a la documentación [aquí](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.invokerequired?view=netframework-4.7.2). También te dejo por aquí un ejemplo de uso:

```
public void Function()
{
     if (this.InvokeRequired)
     {
         this.BeginInvoke(new Action(this.Function));
         return;
     }

    ;         
}
```

Espero que te ayude. Cualquier duda al respecto añádela como comentario y lo vemos.

Un saludo

Comment: Muchas gracias me solucionó el problema, al estar dentro de un hilo `InvokeRequired` siempre está a true. Al final he optado por usar `Invoke` en lugar de `BeginInvoke` debido a que con este ultimo se me bloqueaba el programa completo. La modificación queda tal que así: `Invoke(new Action(app.NextBg));`